# preceding each line by a number when "\n" is also inside quoted records

Tags: awk, gawk

I am running an `awk` script as this:

```
find ~/dir/ -regextype sed -regex '.*\.[0-9]\{3\}\.txt' -exec ~/script.awk {} \;
```

it produces lines by extracting data from files found by `find`. I would like to have each line preceded by an integer number making a sequence, ie. first line by 1, second line by 2 etc. The problem is that one of the columns that `awk` produces has new line symbols `\n` in them, ie. a line from awk can look like:

```
"col1" col2 "col3_\n_col3_continued_\n_more_col3" "col4"
```

such lines are constructed in the `END` part of the script:

```
END {
    method=""
    i=1
    for (i=1;i<nm;i++) {
        if (i==1) {
            method=methodarr[i]
        }
        else {
            method=method"\n"methodarr[i]
        }
    }
    method="\""method"\""
    printf "%s %s %s %s\n",date,time,method,"\""FILENAME"\""
}
```

This results, when displayed that there are more lines that there were files but the records are correctly separated because the new line symbols are enclosed in quotes. The resultant text file is then used for imports as data into some spreadsheet software and the new line separated parts enclosed by apostrophes are correctly put into a single cell. But this prevents a simple add a number before each line.

One simple solution is to assume a format of the first column, pass the result again to `awk`, match the first column format and precede those by the line number. I do not like this approach. Is there a simpler way, ideally without having to assume something about the first column? I would guess some way of global system variable `i` that would be increased by each run of the `awk` but this i have no idea if it is possible or how to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution, I think, is to precede each line with a special character sequence and then replace it with numbers by another AWK script.

For example, replace your code:

```
printf "%s %s %s %s\n",date,time,method,"\""FILENAME"\""
```

with:

```
printf "<LINE_N> %s %s %s %s\n",date,time,method,"\""FILENAME"\""
```

And then run the output through this script to replace `<LINE_N>` with numbers:

```
awk '$1 == "<LINE_N>" { cnt += 1; printf cnt; $1=""; } 1;'
```